Studies on soundness principles of ZFC
I wonder if anyone has done any studies on the (fragments of) soundness principles $\mathrm{RFN(ZFC)}$ of ZFC, by which I mean
$$\mathrm{RFN(ZFC)}=\{ \forall x (\mathrm{Prov}_{\mathrm{ZFC}}(\ulcorner\phi(\dot{x})\urcorner)\to\phi(x))\mid \phi\text{ a formula}\}$$
where $\mathrm{Prov}_{\mathrm{ZFC}}(x)$ means $x$ is ZFC-provable. If $\Gamma$ is a syntactic complexity, $\mathrm{RFN}_{\Gamma}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ means $\mathrm{RFN(ZFC)}$ restricted to $\Gamma$-formulas.
We know that if in $V$ there is a transitive set model $M$ of ZFC then $V\models\mathrm{RFN_{\Pi^1_1}(ZFC)}$ (Mostowski absoluteness), and if moreover $\omega_1^M=\omega_1^V$ then $V\models\mathrm{RFN_{\Pi^1_2}(ZFC)}$ (Shoenfield absoluteness). (So in particular a worldly cardinal implies $\mathrm{RFN_{\Pi^1_2}(ZFC)}$.) Are there more results related to the soundness principles? For example, is there a set-theoretic principle that is equivalent to $\mathrm{RFN_{\Pi^1_2}(ZFC)}$ over ZFC? What about $\mathrm{RFN_{\Pi^0_2}(ZFC)}$? Can we say something for higher complexities?

$\Pi^1_1$-reflection of a theory $T$ extending $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is equivalent to the proof-theoretic ordinal (should be called the proof-theoretic well-order) of $T$ is well-founded. Also, $\Pi^1_2$-reflection of $T$ is equivalent to the proof-theoretic dilator of $T$ is really a dilator. You may find the proof for the latter from Aguilera-Pakhomov's The $\Pi^1_2$ Consequences of a Theory. But I don't think they are set-theoretic principles.

The $\Sigma^1_2$-reflection of a theory $T$ extending $\Sigma^1_2\text{-}\mathsf{AC}_0$ should be equivalent to the existence of a transitive model of $\mathsf{ATR}_0$ plus the $\Sigma^1_2$-consequences of $T$, which should be more set-theoretic. (The height of a resulting model is less than $\delta^1_2$, so this model is not subject to Shoenfield absoluteness.) Unfortunately its proof follows from my unpublished results, so I cannot post my argument right now.
